# Javascript: Unexpected Token [ on line 92

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am having trouble with my html page here. On the console it shows me that there is 1 error on line 92 due to an unexpected token. Im trying to drag the image on the page to a designated box. Once dragged it should stay in the box. When I click on the image i should be able to drag it out of the box. I am not sure where i went wrong, but its completely not working at this point. All help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var pictureIds = 20;
  var Size = 400;
  var table = $('#results').DataTable();

  $.get("https://unsplash.it/list", function(Res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < pictureIds; pictureIds++) {
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * pictureIds.length)

      $('.left').append($("<img>", {
        src: "https://picsum.photos/" + Size + "/" + Size + "?image" + Res[randomNumber].id,
        id: randomNumber,
        class: "leftImg"
      }));

    }

    (".leftImg").draggable({
      revert: "invalid"
    });

    $("#right").droppable({
      accept: ".leftImg",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.attr("id"),
          $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
            top: 2,
            left: 0
          }).appendTo($(this));
        window.alert("Dropped image with an ID of " + ui.draggable.attr('id'));

        //Create rows
        var rowNode = table.row.add({
            Res[image id].id,
            Res[image id].filename,
            Res[image id].author,
            Res[image id].post_url
          }).draw()
          .node();

        table.row.add({
          Res[image id].id,
          Res[image id].filename,
          Res[image id].author,
          Res[image id].post_url
        }).draw();

        $(rowNode).addClass(ui.draggable.attr('id'));

      }

    })

  });
});
```

```css
.left {
  padding: 20px;
  order: solid #000000 2px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 90%;
}

#right {
  width: 30%;
  border: solid #000000 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <!-- head stuff goes here -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />


</head>

<body>

  <!-- HTML content goes here -->

  <div class="left">
    <img class="leftImg" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" id="102" />

    <div id="right">

    </div>

  </div>

  <table id="results" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>filename</th>
        <th>author</th>
        <th>url</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</html>
```

Comment: When I fixed up the snippet (don't enclose CSS / JS in tags), you have a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just got a little overzealous with some editing...  A few typo's and I think you're good:

1. Missing the $ on the line " (".leftImg").draggable({"
2. The line var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * pictureIds.length) needs to have pictureIds.length changed to pictureIds as it is an int not an array.
3. Your loop is on the variable i but you incremented pictureId's instead of i.
4. The part where you are doing table.row.add had Res[image id] and I am not sure what is supposed to be in place if image id but Res[image id] is not valid.  I commented that out in the code below but what I have edited below is draggable into the box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var pictureIds = 20;
  var Size = 400;
  var table = $('#results').DataTable();

  $.get("https://unsplash.it/list", function(Res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < pictureIds; i++) {
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * pictureIds);

      $('.left').append($("<img>", {
        src: "https://picsum.photos/" + Size + "/" + Size + "?image" + Res[randomNumber].id,
        id: randomNumber,
        class: "leftImg"
      }));

    }

    $(".leftImg").draggable({
      revert: "invalid"
    });

    $("#right").droppable({
      accept: ".leftImg",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.attr("id"),
          $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
            top: 2,
            left: 0
          }).appendTo($(this));
        window.alert("Dropped image with an ID of " + ui.draggable.attr('id'));

        //Create rows
        /*
        var rowNode = table.row.add({
            Res[randomNumber].id,
            Res[randomNumber].filename,
            Res[randomNumber].author,
            Res[randomNumber].post_url
          }).draw()
          .node();

        table.row.add({
          Res[randomNumber].id,
          Res[randomNumber].filename,
          Res[randomNumber].author,
          Res[randomNumber].post_url
        }).draw();
        */
        $(rowNode).addClass(ui.draggable.attr('id'));

      }

    })

  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank you for your quick help. I appreciate it.